# Unity Trouble with Lists

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, bitarray

So I am working in Unity right now and I am using a List to keep my values but I am having some troubles. Here's the relevant functions:

```
List<DNA> generation;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    generation = new List<DNA> ();
    generation.Add (new DNA ());
    generation [0].init ();
    Debug.Log (generation[0].Chromosone);
}
```

This Debug sends out Null.

In my DNA class:

```
public void init(){

    this.Chromosone = new BitArray (36);

    for(int i = 0; i  < this.Chromosone.Length; i++){
        if(Random.Range(0,2) == 1)
            this.Chromosone.Set(i,true);
        else
            this.Chromosone.Set(i,false);
    }

    lifeTime = Random.Range (1, 3);
    Debug.Log (Chromosone);

}
```

This Debug sends out that it is a BitArray.

EDIT: If I return Chromosone, I get the BitArray as a return. But the second I lose my link, (next line), Chromosone ceases to exist.

EDIT of EDIT: Changing List to an array of DNA corrects the problem but I need the length to be modifiable. So that's not helping so much...

Comment: I just tested this myself after seeing no possible explanation, and both are set to a non-null value. Try making Chromosone a property, and put a breakpoint on the setter to see what it is being set to. (Something outside of what you posted is interfering)

Comment: Chromosone is already a property and how could something outside interfere when one function calls the other?

Comment: Well, something else you posted here is causing this, as I made a replica as a console application and it works perfect. [Add a breakpoint like this](http://i.imgur.com/WXG2iZG.png) and inspect the value of `value`. If it is null than follow the call stack to find the reason.

Comment: I made a mistake, it's not a property. The Set is from the BitArray itself.

Comment: If it is a field you can easily make it a property as seen in the image.

Comment: It being a property or a field won't change anything.

Comment: Yes but if you put a breakpoint on the property setter you can see what is setting it (and why it is null), that is what I am trying to say.

Comment: why not use a bool[] instead?

Comment: also is chromosone a class or variable name? since the name is capital

Comment: @WillFisher I am not using bool[] since I need the length to be variable. Also, using bool[] is not the problem here apparently. and it's a variable, I just fudged up and decided not to change it for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated these scripts in Unity using a bool[] instead of a BitArray as this is much more customary. The code you would use would be:
MainClass:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainClass : MonoBehaviour {

    private List<DNA> generation = new List<DNA>();
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        generation.Add(new DNA());
        generation[0].init();
        for(int i = 0; i < generation[0].boolLength; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(generation[0].chromosone[i]);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

DNA Class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DNA : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool[] chromosone;
    public int boolLength = 36;
    public int lifeTime;

    public void init()
    {
        this.chromosone = new bool[boolLength];
        for(int i = 0; i < boolLength; i++)
        {
            if(Random.Range (0,2) == 1)
                this.chromosone[i] = true;
            else
                this.chromosone[i] = false;
        }
        lifeTime = Random.Range(1,3);
    }
}
```

And of course I'm assuming you only pasted the relevant code in the question so make sure to add back in the rest. One thing to note however, in the MainClass make sure you include the line `using System.Collections.Generic` so that you can access the List type.
**EDIT:**
If incase you must use a BitArray, all you would have to do is change the DNA class to:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DNA : MonoBehaviour {

    public BitArray chromosone;
    public int boolLength = 36;
    public int lifeTime;

    public void init()
    {
        this.chromosone = new BitArray(boolLength);
        for(int i = 0; i < boolLength; i++)
        {
            if(Random.Range (0,2) == 1)
                this.chromosone.Set(i, true);
            else
                this.chromosone.Set(i, false);
        }
        lifeTime = Random.Range(1,3);
    }
}
```

What I am guessing your issue was, was that you were either not correctly iterating through the chromosone variable to debug it, because it is not null, or... you did not include `using System.Collections.Generic`